# Launch an ESB task from UI

Tags: wso2, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

I write some scheduled tasks in WSO2 ESB who are launched using count and interval or by a cron expression.

Now , i like to create an UI for launching those task using a link or bouton (bouton1 -> launch task1 ...).
Is there a way to do that ??

Answer (score 0):

You can use management console-->Task UI to schedule the task..

Answer (score 0):

A task will be executed as soon as you create it. Currently there is no way to launch a task from an external ui. This is a limitation in the current ESB schedule tasks implementation.